# Windows batch script random order of insert to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I have a text file that I read which contains multiple lines of words. For now it contains "Successful" and failed.

Here's my code.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 50) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (D:\Errors.txt) do echo %%x %%a >>D:\list.txt
)
```

Basically what I want to output are the words in Errors.txt at random which is mapped from 1 - 50.

Currently this is the output of my code and it's not at random. Also the numbering repeats which I guess is expected due to the loop. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks!

```
1 Successful 
1 Failed 
2 Successful 
2 Failed 
3 Successful 
3 Failed 
4 Successful 
4 Failed 
5 Successful 
5 Failed 
6 Successful 
6 Failed 
7 Successful 
7 Failed
```

Basically end goal should be like this. Successful/Failed are applied at random while the numbers 1 - 50 are consistent.

```
1 Successful 
2 Failed
3 Failed
4 Successful
5 Successful
6 Successful
7 Failed
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to provide a useful solution, please try to reword/improve it through use of the edit facility.

Comment: Thanks for editting!

Comment: You have not improved your question as I asked. The file you have used in the code you have posted, `Errors.txt`, appears to only contain two lines, line 1:`Successful` and line 2:`Failed`. How is 1 - 50 relevant? What do you want as your end goal?

Comment: End goal is like this. line 1: 1 Successful line 2: 2 Failed. Line 3: Could be Successful could be failed. Line 4: Could be successful / or failed. and so on.

Comment: How is `D:\Errors.txt` relevant? because I can create a fifty line file containing a randomly written choice of two strings without reading in a seemingly unrelated file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works with any number of lines in the `Errors.txt` file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(

rem Load the lines from the file
set n=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (D:\Errors.txt) do (
   set "line[!n!]=%%a"
   set /A n+=1
   echo !n! %%a
)

rem Repeat same lines the rest of times in random order
set /A nP1=n+1
for /L %%i in (!nP1!,1,50) do (
   set /A i=!random! %% n
   call echo %%i %%line[!i!]%%
)

) > D:\list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
(
  REM read from file
  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (D:\Errors.txt) do (
    set /a n+=1
    echo !n! %%a 
  )
  REM for the rest until 50:
  for /l %%a in (!n!,1,49) do (
    set /a n+=1
    set /a x=!random! %% 2
    if !x!==0 (
      echo !n! successful
    ) else (
      echo !n! failed
    )
  )
)>D:\list.txt
type D:\list.txt
```

Comment: THANK YOU. This is just what I needed.

Comment: This method does _not_ use the lines from the `Errors` file in the rest of lines; just in the first two lines...

Comment: oh yeah I just noticed it now. three below entries did not came from the .txt. it came from the loop. Thanks for the help!